# How to find the index of a multi-dimensional array which has the maximum value

Tags: c, arrays

I have this code sample to find the Maximum Usage days which works like a charm. But I need to get which `array index` has the maximum value. I tried many methods, but couldn't come up with a solution. This is what I have tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float maximumDayUsage=0,minimumDayDayUsage=0;
    int whichDayHasMaximumUsage;
    float usage[7][5]={ {1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 4.1},
                        {1.0, 1.3, 4.0, 1.5, 7.8},
                        {3.2, 1.0, 1.3, 4.0, 9.5},
                        {1.5, 3.2, 2.3, 0.4, 7.4}, 
                        {1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 4.1},
                        {2.6, 2.1, 1.7, 7.0, 13.4},
                        {1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 4.1} };
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(usage[i][j]>maximumDayUsage){
                maximumDayUsage=usage[i][j];
                whichDayHasMaximumUsage++; 
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
    printf("Usage: %.2f\n",maximumDayUsage);
    printf("Which Day: %d",whichDayHasMaximumUsage);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `whichDayHasMaximumUsage` every time you find a new highest value? Wouldn't it make more sense to store the index values `i` and `j` somewhere instead?

Comment: Yes I thought I got there wrong. Can you tell me at least a hint to store that `index` value which bears the maximum value???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just save the `i` and `j` indexes of the maximum usage day when you iterate over the array:

```
int max_i = 0;
int max_j = 0;
float maximumDayUsage = 0;
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        if(usage[i][j] > maximumDayUsage) {
            maximumDayUsage = usage[i][j];
            max_i = i;
            max_j = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can this `max_i` and `max_j` will hold the `index` which has the maximum value??? can you clarify your answer?

Comment: @user7980830 `max_i` and `max_j` will hold the index of the maximum value for the exact same reason that `maximumDayUsage` will hold the maximum value itself. This might be a good time to learn how to use a debugger (like GDB). Step through your code and see how the values change as your program runs.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Even if we try to assign the values for `max_i` and `max_j` with the indexes having maximum values, How can I get which index has the maximum of all???

Comment: @user7980830 Well, think about it. How does `maximumDayUsage` end up holding the maximum value?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you very much Sir :)